# ?Help command not doing what is intended and message logger returning false errors in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

so here is my code in events/messages:

```java
module.exports = {
    name: 'message',
    execute(message) {
        console.log(`\nServer: ${message.guild.name}\nChannel #${message.channel.name}\nUser: ${message.author.tag}\nContent:\n${message.content}`);
    },
};
```

the purpose of the above code is to say something like this in console:

```
Server: Nyomi's server
Channel #general
User: Torcenta#3619
Content:
?help
```

and here is my help command:

```java
const { prefix } = require('../../config.json');

module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: 'List all of my commands or info about a specific command.',
    aliases: ['commands'],
    usage: '[command name]',
    cooldown: 5,
    execute(message, args) {
        const data = [];
        const { commands } = message.client;

        if (!args.length) {
            data.push('Here\'s a list of all my commands:');
            data.push(commands.map(command => command.name).join(', '));
            data.push(`\nYou can send \`${prefix}help [command name]\` to get info on a specific command!`);

            return message.author.send(data, { split: true })
                .then(() => {
                    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
                    message.reply('I\'ve sent you a DM with all my commands!');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(`Could not send help DM to ${message.author.tag}.\n`, error);
                    message.reply('it seems like I can\'t DM you! Do you have DMs disabled?');
                });

        }

        const name = args[0].toLowerCase();
        const command = commands.get(name) || commands.find(c => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(name));

        if (!command) {
            return message.reply('that\'s not a valid command!');
        }

        data.push(`**Name:** ${command.name}`);

        if (command.aliases) data.push(`**Aliases:** ${command.aliases.join(', ')}`);
        if (command.description) data.push(`**Description:** ${command.description}`);
        if (command.usage) data.push(`**Usage:** ${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}`);

        data.push(`**Cooldown:** ${command.cooldown || 3} second(s)`);

        message.channel.send(data, { split: true });


    },
};
```

but whenever I say ?help in chat, it gives me an error:

```
Could not send help DM to Torcenta#3619.
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
    at Object.execute (/home/runner/Nyomi/events/message.js:4:42)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Nyomi/index.js:37:61)
    at Client.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/Nyomi/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at /home/runner/Nyomi/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:175:52
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

and in chat the bot responds with

```
<@442082888209399808>, it seems like I can't DM you! Do you have DMs disabled?
```

(I am <@442082888209399808> it is @ing me)
yet the bot dms me the help command and I can see all of the commands.

and sometimes, when doing the ?help command, it crashes the bot with the following error:

```
/home/runner/Nyomi/events/message.js:4
        console.log(`\nServer: ${message.guild.name}\nChannel #${message.channel.name}\nUser: ${message.author.tag}\nContent:\n${message.content}`);
                                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
    at Object.execute (/home/runner/Nyomi/events/message.js:4:42)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Nyomi/index.js:37:61)
    at Client.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/Nyomi/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/Nyomi/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/Nyomi/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/Nyomi/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/Nyomi/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/Nyomi/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
```

I am fairly new to this, and request that you help me understand what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: This occurs when the message was sent in a DM, and as such `Message#guild` will be null. Make a check before accessing `Message#guild#name`

Comment: @Diamond so how would I make a check before accessing `message.guild.name`? would I just make an if statement before?

Comment: That is exactly what I did, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

answered by @Diamond

updated the events/message code to be:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'message',
    execute(message) {
        if(message.channel.type === 'dm'){
            console.log(`\nMessage was made in DM's\nUser: ${message.author.tag}\nContent:\n${message.content}`)
        } else {
        console.log(`\nServer: ${message.guild.name}\nChannel #${message.channel.name}\nUser: ${message.author.tag}\nContent:\n${message.content}`);}
    },
};
```